# What is the difference between Arduino board and Genuino Board?

Tags: arduino-uno, genuino

I've got an Arduino UNO REV3 SMD EDITION.

In the Arduino Editor, I've selected `Arduino/Genuino Uno`.

In a tutorial, I saw `Hardware required : Arduino or Genuino Board`

What is the difference between Arduino board and Genuino Board?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name Genuino grew out of the split between Massimo and Gianluca (aided in part by Microsoft of course, and a trademark wrangle that went wrong). Each side wanted to appear to be more "genuine" than the other. That lead to the "Genuino" name (a *genuine* Arduino), and a version number war with the IDE.

Both sides started making their own variants of boards, with some only available from the USA (Arduino) and others only outside the USA (Genuino).

Since they have patched up their differences now the two boards are one and the same. A Genuino Uno and an Arduino Uno are the exact same board. They always have been, there has just been arguments over the name.

Comment: At this moment I think people use term "Genuino" to describe the "original board" from official website, and "Arduino" as "any compatible board" including the 2$ Chinese clones.

Comment: Not so. I see Arduino as the originally made boards, and clone as anything else. Arduino's use Atmega16U2 (Uno & Mega) or FT232 (Nano) for USB/Serial, while $2 clones use CH340g for that purpose. I use FT232 or FT232 modules in my designs as the US distributors do not carry CH340g chips, and I won't design in parts I cannot source from reputable suppliers.